# Why can't I delete the "__hash__" attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, built-in

I can't seem to create an object without a `__hash__` attribute (that is for which `hasattr(Obj, "__hash__")` returns `False`). I was trying to do this for testing purposes, but now I am curious why I can't. The few things I have tried are the following:

```
class NoHash(object):
    def __init__(self):
        delattr(self, "__hash__")
```

This yields the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/irh/poly/tests/test_poly.py", line 23, in setUp
    self.no_hash = NoHash()
  File "/home/irh/poly/tests/test_poly.py", line 15, in __init__
    delattr(self, "__hash__")
AttributeError: __hash__
```

This code yields no errors:

```
class NoHash(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__hash__ = None
        delattr(self, "__hash__")
```

but I get that `nhash = NoHash(); print(hasattr(nhash, "__hash__"))` still gives me true. Just curious what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the underlying C implementation the `__hash__` method is actually implemented in a function pointed to by the [type structure](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html); it does not exist as an ordinary attribute, so it is impossible to delete it.

If you want to indicate that a type does not implement a `__hash__` method then you should assign `None` to the attribute instead.

Comment: Sorry if this is exceedingly dumb thing to ask... but the question was about python. Do you mean the underlying C implementation of the python?

Comment: Yes. That would be why I linked to the piece of documentation that I did.

Comment: wow, sorry, didn't even notice the link. Thanks for the answer.